# Login when successfully updated the data of the user in Laravel

Tags: laravel

**RegisterController.php**

I added here an update function so that when the user wants to login with Facebook, he/she will be redirected to a form and then fill the fields so that their information will be stored in the Database.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if ($data['userEmail']) {
        return User::where('email', $data['userEmail'])
            ->update([
                'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
                'address' => $data['address'],
                'country' => $data['country'],
                'city' => $data['city'],
                'zip_code' => $data['zip_code'],
                'state' => $data['state'],
                'is_online' => true,
            ]);
    } else {
        return User::create([
            'full_name' => $data['full_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'zip_code' => $data['zip_code'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'is_online' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The error when the IF statement returns true is this

> "Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface
>   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, integer given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\esoftwaredeals\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php
>   on line 35".

However, if it returns false, there will be no error and a new user is created and will automatically redirect to the "/my-account" page which is where I wanted to redirect when the user successfully updated their information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `User` instance from the `create()` method:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if ($data['userEmail']) {
        $user = User::where('email', $data['userEmail'])->first();
        $user->update([
                'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
                'address' => $data['address'],
                'country' => $data['country'],
                'city' => $data['city'],
                'zip_code' => $data['zip_code'],
                'state' => $data['state'],
                'is_online' => true,
            ]);
    } else {
        $user = User::create([
            'full_name' => $data['full_name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'country' => $data['country'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'zip_code' => $data['zip_code'],
            'state' => $data['state'],
            'is_online' => true,
        ]);
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Also, you should use the [`updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method to keep the code maintainable. For example:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);

    return User::updateOrCreate(
        array_only($data, ['email', 'full_name']),
        array_except($data, ['email', 'full_name'])
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An update query returns the number of rows that where affected by the update query.So when the update user is successful it will return 1.

The create method returns the saved model instance. So this is causing the issue in your code.

You can use find and save method provided by eloquent and return the user object in if statement and it will work.

```
$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
$user->firstname = $firstname;
$user->lastname = $lastname;
$user->save();
return $user;
```

Try like this and it should work.

Answer (score -1):

```
             $user = User::find($usuario->ID);
             $user->rol_id = 1;
             $user->save();
         }
      }
  }


    return view('dashboard.index')->with(compact('cantReferidosDirectos', 'cantReferidosIndirectos', 'cantReferidosActivos', 'fechaProxActivacion', 'new_member',
                'cantventas', 'cantventasmont', 'fullname', 'rangos', 'cantAllUsers', 'rankingComisiones', 'rankingVentas', 'permiso','noticias', 'contTicket', 'moneda',
                'nombreRol'
        ));
}

/**
 * Permite actualizar las informacion de los usuarios 
 * 
 * @access public
 * @return view
 */
public function ActualizarTodo()
{
    $comisiones = new ComisionesController;
    $comisiones->ObtenerUsuarios();
    $todousers = $this->generarArregloUsuario(Auth::user()->ID);
    foreach ($todousers as $user ) {
        if ($user['rol'] != 0) {
            $activacion = new ActivacionController;
            $activacion->activarUsuarios($user['ID']);
        }
    }
```

Arguments
"compact(): Undefined variable: fechaProxActivacion"
Como soluciono este error

Comment: Your code needs a lot more explanation and is fairly messy. I'd recommend cleaning it up in order to avoid more downvoting.